# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then') - while Mocking Fetch call in Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, fetch-api

This is the file containing the fetch call, which just sends some locally stored json file.

```
// eslint-disable-next-line import/prefer-default-export
export const get = () => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
  return fetch('data/posts.json').then((res) => res.json());
};
```

My test where I mock the `fetch` method and `Promise.resolve` a mock array.

```
import { get } from './posts';

const mockData = [
  {
    "id": "ig-1",
    "accountId": "IG",
    "accountIcon": "/images/ig-icon.svg",
    "accountName": "IG account",
    "accountImageInitial": "J",
    "imageUrl": "/images/social_logo.png",
    "caption": "test",
    "timestamp": 1635510651638
  },
  {
    "id": "fb-1",
    "accountId": "FB",
    "accountIcon": "/images/fb-icon.svg",
    "accountName": "FB account",
    "accountImageInitial": "J",
    "imageUrl": "/images/social_logo.png",
    "caption": "test",
    "timestamp": 1635510051638
  }
];

global.fetch = jest.fn(() => 
  Promise.resolve({
    json: () => Promise.resolve(mockData)
  })
);

describe('The posts API controller', () => {
  test('get() returns expected default payload', async () => {
    const result = await get();
    expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(result).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

      2 | export const get = () => {
      3 |   // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    > 4 |   return fetch('data/posts.json').then((res) => res.json());
        |          ^
      5 | };
```

[image]

Unsure as to why I'm getting this error, as it appears that I have mocked fetch correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest just to return the `res.json()`, which you are actually already doing implicitly.
Also, after  `.then()`  it's good practice to have `.catch()` in case you encounter an error during fetching.

So, try following.

```
export const get = () => {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then((res) => res.json()) // this is an implicit return
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

or using async/await

```
const get = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
    return res.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, also found out that I didn't need to mock the get, just the fetch. Also fixed my Fetch mock like so `global.fetch = () => Promise.resolve({ json: () => Promise.resolve(mockData) })`